# Using @material-ui/core, how do I make a Slider where the track is divided into left and right with different colors?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

The slider goes from -10 to +10. From -10 to 0, the color should be red. From 0 to +10, the color should be green.

How can I achieve this using the `<Slider />` from `@material-ui/core`?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you meant the rail or the track element of the `Slider` - this example styles both. Essentially, it's just a case of targeting the correct classes which are exposed to you by the Material-UI API. You can get a full list of the `Slider` element's classes [here](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/).

The background of the rail can be styled with a simple linear-gradient image generated by CSS, and the track itself can be conditionally styled by passing a prop to the `makeStyles` function:

```
import React from "react";

import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  rail: {
    background: "linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, green 50%)"
  },
  track: {
    background: ({ value }) => (value >= 0 ? "green" : "red")
  }
});

const marks = Array.from({ length: 21 }, (_, i) => ({
  value: i - 10,
  label: i - 10
}));

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const classes = useStyles({ value });

  return (
    <Slider
      onChange={(e, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
      max={10}
      min={-10}
      value={value}
      classes={classes}
      marks={marks}
      step={1}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Taking your comment at face-value, you can also pass the `value` prop to the rail and style it conditionally. You shouldn't ever need to style the left hand side of the rail gray because it will always be covered by up the track in that situation:

```
rail: {
    background: ({ value }) =>
      `linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, ${value < 0 ? "gray" : "green"} 50%)`
},
```

Otherwise, I would just get rid of the `track` element altogether and push up the opacity of the rail while accounting for the two different sides via two conditionals:

```
rail: {
  opacity: 0.7,
  background: ({ value }) => {
    const left = value < 0 ? "red" : "gray";
    const right = value < 0 ? "gray" : "green";
    return `linear-gradient(90deg, ${left} 50%, ${right} 50%)`;
  }
},
track: {
  display: "none",
}
```

Comment: I meant the track. But I manage to get it to work simply by removing a few lines from your solution. Now, I left out a bit of detail. How do you make the colors of the rail dynamic? If the value is less than zero, then the left side is red while the right side is gray. If the value is greater than zero, then the right side is green while the left side is gray?

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/metrics-color-threshold-slider-reversed-forked-33sw5x?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A100%2C65-100%2C69

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Box, Typography, Slider } from "@mui/material";

function DiscreteSlider(props) {
  const {
    entityName,
    reverse,
    values,
    min,
    max,
    thresholdMarks,
    thresholdMarksTitles,
    style,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  const [value, setValue] = useState(
    reverse ? values.map((val) => -val) : values
  );
  const [marks, setMarks] = useState(
    reverse ? thresholdMarks.map((val) => -val) : thresholdMarks
  );
  const [perc, setPerc] = useState(
    reverse
      ? values.map((val) => parseInt((1 - Math.abs(val / max)) * 100))
      : values.map((val) => (val / max) * 100)
  );

  const onChange = (e, tValues) => {
    const [minVal, maxVal] = tValues;
    if (maxVal > minVal && maxVal !== minVal) {
      setValue(tValues);
      if (!reverse) {
        setMarks([
          parseInt((min + minVal) / 2, 10),
          parseInt((minVal + maxVal) / 2, 10),
          parseInt((maxVal + max) / 2, 10),
        ]);
        setPerc(tValues.map((val) => (val / max) * 100));
      } else {
        setMarks([
          parseInt((-max + minVal) / 2, 10),
          parseInt((minVal + maxVal) / 2, 10),
          parseInt((maxVal + -min) / 2, 10),
        ]);
        setPerc(
          tValues.map((val) => parseInt((1 - Math.abs(val / max)) * 100))
        );
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(value, perc, marks);
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: "80%",
        margin: "16px",
      }}
    >
      <Typography
        id="discrete-slider"
        gutterBottom
        sx={{
          marginBottom: "40px",
        }}
      >
        {entityName}
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        sx={{
          "& .MuiSlider-track": {
            background: "#47D7AC",
            borderColor: "#47D7AC",
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
            [`&:nth-of-type(${1}n)`]: {
              background: "#FAB46D",
              "& span": {
                background: "#FAB46D",
              },
            },
            [`&:nth-of-type(${2}n)`]: {
              background: "#47D7AC",
              "& span": {
                background: "#47D7AC",
              },
            },
            [`&:nth-of-type(${3}n)`]: {
              background: "#47D7AC",
              "& span": {
                background: "#47D7AC",
              },
            },
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
            background: "none",
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-rail": {
            background: `linear-gradient(to right, #FAB46D 0% ${perc[0]}%, #47D7AC ${perc[0]}% ${perc[1]}%, grey ${perc[1]}% 100%)`,
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-valueLabel": {},
          ...style,
        }}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        valueLabelFormat={(x) => `< ${x}`}
        value={value}
        min={reverse ? -max : min}
        max={reverse ? -min : max}
        scale={(x) => (reverse ? -x : x)}
        marks={[
          { value: reverse ? -max : min, label: reverse ? max : min },
          ...marks.map((val, idx) => ({
            value: val,
            label: thresholdMarksTitles[idx],
          })),
          { value: reverse ? -min : max, label: reverse ? min : max },
        ]}
        onChange={onChange}
        // disabled
        {...rest}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default function ThresholdSlider() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <DiscreteSlider
        entityName="Reverse custom range"
        reverse={true}
        step={1}
        values={[10.0, 4.0]}
        min={0}
        max={24}
        thresholdMarks={[17, 7, 2]}
        thresholdMarksTitles={["R", "Y", "G"]}
      />
      <DiscreteSlider
        entityName="Normal range"
        reverse={false}
        step={1}
        values={[4, 5, 7]}
        min={0}
        max={10}
        thresholdMarks={[3, 5, 8]}
        thresholdMarksTitles={["R", "Y", "G"]}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).